# jQuery ui Autocomplete: Add the selected value to the dropdown and avoiding duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-select, jquery-ui-autocomplete

https://jsfiddle.net/shucode/xxbkrowr/

For each value populated I want it's associated labels in the drop down list.

I have tried but list is appended with all results not just the ones I need.

Please see my fiddle

```
$("#two").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#two").val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $("#two").val(ui.item.value);

            $.each(availableTags, function (key, value) {
                var option = $('<option />').val(value.label).text(value.label);
                $("#jobTypeD").append(option);
            });
            share = ui.item.label;
            alert(share);
            return false;
        },
        minLength: 0,
        autofocus: true
    });
```

Comment: Which results you want to be appended to the dropdown? Please provide a clear explanation.

Comment: I want the labels of each value value to be appended to the dropdown. Also don't want duplication of values in the autocomplete search. I am doing mostly C# but JS is tough!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your fiddle and here is the working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/bobhuLes/1/)

Now only the value selected in the autocomplete will be added in the dropdown and duplicates will not be added. Here is the modified JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags =
         [
             { "id": "2", "value": "CCTV / Satellites / Alarms", "label": "Aerial \u0026 satellite dish installation" },
             { "id": "2", "value": "CCTV / Satellites / Alarms", "label": "Burglar, security \u0026 intruder alarm installation" },
             { "id": "2", "value": "CCTV / Satellites / Alarms", "label": "CCTV installation" },
             { "id": "2", "value": "CCTV / Satellites / Alarms", "label": "Digital Home Network" },
             { "id": "2", "value": "CCTV / Satellites / Alarms", "label": "Fire alarm installation" },
             { "id": "2", "value": "CCTV / Satellites / Alarms", "label": "Sound \u0026 Audio Visual Installation" },
             { "id": "3", "value": "Bathroom Fitter", "label": "Fit Bath" }
         ];

        $("#two").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#two").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            select: function (e, ui) {
                $("#two").val(ui.item.label);

                //check if selected value already exists in the dropdown, if not then append the option to the dropdown
                if($("#jobTypeD option").filter(function (i, o) { return o.value === ui.item.label; })
               .length <= 0)
                {
                        var option = $('<option />').val(ui.item.label).text(ui.item.label);
                                        $("#jobTypeD").append(option);
                    alert("selected value is now added to the dropdown");
                }
                else {
                alert("The selected value already exists in the dropdown and is dulicate. So it will not be added to the dropdown.");
                }


                /*$.each(availableTags, function (key, value) {
                    var option = $('<option />').val(value.label).text(value.label);
                    $("#jobTypeD").append(option);
                });*/
                share = ui.item.label;
                //alert(share);
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 0,
            autofocus: true
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But this is clearly not doing what I have asked for. It should be easy for JS guys. However I will re-iterate my need. I need the first value i.e. CCTV / Satellites or Bathroom Fitter to be selected first. And as we can see each selected value may have multiple labels. So I don't want multiple values in autopop but I need all the labels for each selected value in the list. And yes duplication shouldn't happen in the autopopulate. I can probably flip it upside down and do it the other way but wondering if what I am requesting is possible at all.